# Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)) when running through Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, windows-services, ms-office

i am try to hook to outlook application from windows Service but getting an exception Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))  here is my code.

```
   public void ItemSendEvent()
    {
        try
        {
           if (Process.GetProcessesByName(ApplicationConstants.OUTLOOK_PROCESS_NAME).Count() > 0)
                {
                    // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                    outlookApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject(ApplicationConstants.OUTLOOK_APPLICATION_NAME) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace(ApplicationConstants.OUTLOOK_NAME_SPACE);
                    nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                    nameSpace = null;
                    outlookApplication.ItemSend += outlookApplication_ItemSend;
                }
                log.Info("Outlook Item Send event registered successfully.");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Exception occurred while registering Outlook Item Send event. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but the same code when i launch it through Windows Form Application its working Fine. i gone through some site's and they were saying that outlook object is not in ROT Table. what will be the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Outlook, or any other Office app, cannot run in a Windows service even if your service is running as an interactive user. Only Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or an Extended MAPI wrapper like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family objects) can be used in a service.

In your particular case, it looks like you are trying to trap the `Application.ItemSend` event. There is absolutely no reason to create a Windows service for that. Create a COM addin - it will be loaded by Outlook and run as long as Outlook itself is running in the same process in the same security context.

Comment: hello dmitry i have created a winforms application that absolutely working fine and able to get item send event and grab all the details but i want this to be run in background as services and silently capture all the details.:)

Comment: Once again, you will not be able to since the security contexts are different. You really need to write a COM addin (dll) which will be loaded in-proc by Outlook.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko so just to be clear - if we use Redemption or Extended MPI can we access Outlook from another user process (not necessarily a service)?

Comment: You would not be able to access Outlook or marshal Namespace.MAPIOBJECT (which is IMAPISession) from the outlook.exe address space if the security contexts are different, but you would be able to load the MAPI system in-proc (since it is a set of dlls) and create your own MAPI session using the same profile. Now if that profile uses cached mode, sharing the OST or PST files in that profile might be a problem, but you can always dynamically create your own temporary profile to access a particular Exchange mailbox (or use RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox in case of Redemption).

Answer (score 4):

Two common issues could cause this.

The first would be that you are running Visual Studio in Administrator mode and you are starting your program from within VS, and the Office application is not. To fix that, you need to run your Office application with elevated privileges, in Administrator mode, as well.

The second could be caused by the application not being fully started/loaded when you call `Marshal.GetActiveObject(...)`.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not correct, but Dmitry's answer is

Comment: Yes, When I change the mode in VS (not as an admin), I didn't get the exception

Comment: This is correct, I was having the same issue, was running VS in admin mode, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Old, but still significant thread.

I collided with this error when tried to access Outlook data using the [MS example](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-and-log-on-to-an-instance-of-outlook).

Treating the error in a ***Try / Catch block*** and offering the option of newing Outlook solves the problem:

```
const int ERROR_HRESULT_0x800401E3_MK_E_UNAVAILABLE= -2147221021;
        Outlook.Application application = null;
        // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Any())
        {
            try
            {
                // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //This is the branch where you can get correctly the current Outlook instance
                if (ex.HResult == ERROR_HRESULT_0x800401E3_MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)
                {
                    application = new Outlook.Application();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            application = new Outlook.Application();
        }
```

Although the newing trick functions, no other Outlook instance is created, [as Outlook behaves like a Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35381905/2752308).

I only tested it with Office 365 64 bits installed.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to have your application as a service to get it on the background ...

if your winform work well, just put your winform in background running on the systray for instance